# A media player application design issue - Best approach to implement opening Media files

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, media-player

I'm creating a Media player application with Unity3D and C#.

(My question is not related to Unity, it's a pure design problem)

Here is what I currently have:

1. an `IApp` interface, with implementers:

   1. `TextViewer`
   2. `ImageViewer`
   3. `MediaPlayer`
2. an `IFile` interface, with implementers:

   1. `TextFile`
   2. `ImageFile`
   3. `MediaFile` - with children:

      1. `VideoFile`
      2. `AudioFile`

Here's the interface:

```
public interface IApp
{
  void Open(IFile file);
  Type SupportedType { get; }
}
```

Each app has a specific supported file type it could open.

A word about my `MediaPlayer`, is that it opens/plays both Audio and Video files. But the way I open videos, is different from the way I open audios, so there's a unique logic for each.

Now here's the code - very simple (but not fully implemented yet):

```
public class MediaPlayer : IApp
{
    public Type SupportedType { get { return typeof(MediaFile); } }
    public void Open(IFile file)
    {
        if (file is MediaFile)
            Console.WriteLine("MediaPlayer opening media file...");
    }

    List<MediaFile> Medias = new List<MediaFile>();
    public MediaFile Current { private set; get; }
    public PlaybackControls Controls { private set; get; }
    public PlaybackSettings Settings { private set; get; }

    public MediaPlayer()
    {
       Controls = new PlaybackControls(this);
       Settings = new PlaybackSettings(this);
    }

    public class PlaybackControls
    {
        private MediaPlayer player;
        private int index;
        public PlaybackControls(MediaPlayer player)
        {
            this.player = player;
        }
        public void Seek(float pos) { }
        public void Next()
        {
            index = (index + 1) % player.Medias.Count;
            player.Current = player.Medias[index];
        }
        public void Previous()
        {
            index--;
            if (index < 0)
                index = player.Medias.Count - 1;
            player.Current = player.Medias[index];
        }
        private void PlayVideo(VideoFile video)
        {
            // video logic
        }
        private void PlayAudio(AudioFile audio)
        {
            // audio logic
        }
        public void Play(MediaFile media)
        {
            IsPlaying = true;
            if (media is AudioFile)
                PlayAudio(media as AudioFile);
            else if (media is VideoFile)
                PlayVideo(media as VideoFile);
        }
        public void Play()
        {
            Play(player.Current);
        }
        public void Pause()
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
            Seek(0);
        }
        public bool IsPlaying { get; private set; }
    }

    public class PlaybackSettings
    {
        // Volume, shuffling, looping, etc
    }
}
```

The thing that I don't quite like, is the `Play(Media)` method. Inside, I'm doing a check upon the media type, and depending on whether the media is a video or audio, I'm calling the right method. I don't like that, I don't feel it's quite right. What if I had other types of media, like picture? what if I wanted to move `ImageFile` under `MediaFile`?
I would then have to add another `else-if` statement, which isn't polymorphic at all.

What I could do instead, is let the media files choose what method to call, like:

```
public abstract class MediaFile : IFile
{
   //...
   public abstract void Open(MediaPlayer from);
   //...
}

public class AudioFile : MediaFile
{
   public override void Open(MediaPlayer from)
   {
      from.PlayAudio(this);
   }
}

public class VideoFile : MediaFile
{
   public override void Open(MediaPlayer from)
   {
      from.PlayVideo(this);
   }
}
```

Now in the `MediaPlayer`:

```
public void Open(MediaFile media)
{
  media.Open(this); // polymorphically open it
}
```

No more else-if, nice! But this introduces other inconveniences I don't like:

1. `VideoFile` & `MediaPlayer` and `AudioFile` & `MediaPlayer` are now more tightly coupled.
2. There's now a circular dependency (`MediaPlayer` has to know about `Audio/VideoFile` and vise versa)
3. I don't think it makes sense for the `Audio/VideoFile`s to be able to open themselves, by themselves (although they're not really doing so, they're just telling the `MediaPlayer` how to open them. The `MediaPlayer` should know how to, he doesn't need anyone telling him how to do his work.)
4. It feels very redundant, it's like asking somebody to point at his ear, so he wraps his right hand around his head, and points to his left ear instead of right! - What's happening is that we're going:

either

```
MediaPlayer.Open(Media) -> AudioFile.Open(AudioFile) -> MediaPlayer.OpenAudio(AudioFile)
```

or

```
MediaPlayer.Open(Media) -> VideoFile.Open(VideoFile) -> MediaPlayer.OpenVideo(VideoFile)
```

We're circling around ourselves, in the name of polymorphism where we could have just gone directly to the right methods.

I think both the two above approaches are not best, but if I were to choose one, I would go for the first.

What do you think? Is there a better way? - A nice, elegant, robust polymorphic way that shoots all birds with one stone? How should I have gone about this? Maybe there's a design pattern I could use here?

And please correct me if I was wrong in my judgement.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple options.

1) Use dictionary of delegates and select based on file type, which delegate to run:

```
public class PlaybackControls
    {
        private MediaPlayer player;
        private int index;
        Dictionary<string, Action<MediaFile>> _fileActionMethods;

        public PlaybackControls(MediaPlayer player)
        {
            this.player = player;

            _fileActionMethods = new Dictionary<string, Action<MediaFile>>();
            _fileActionMethods.Add(typeof(VideoFile).Name, x => PlayVideoFile(x));
            _fileActionMethods.Add(typeof(AudioFile).Name, x => PlayAudioFile(x));
        }

        public void Seek(float pos) { }
        public void Next()
        {
            index = (index + 1) % player.Medias.Count;
            player.Current = player.Medias[index];
        }
        public void Previous()
        {
            index--;
            if (index < 0)
                index = player.Medias.Count - 1;
            player.Current = player.Medias[index];
        }

        public void Play(MediaFile media)
        {
            IsPlaying = true;

            _fileActionMethods[media.GetType().Name](media);
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            Play(player.Current);
        }
        public void Pause()
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
            Seek(0);
        }
        public bool IsPlaying { get; private set; }

        private void PlayVideoFile(MediaFile file) { }

        private void PlayAudioFile(MediaFile file) { }
    }
```

2) Second option is based on similar concept of dynamic selection, but uses another layer of abstraction that enables you to handle each file using separate class. For lack of imagination I am naming it `IFileActionHandler.` It has only one method now but you can add more, if you need to. The sample below shows how to dynamically select the correct implementation based on the file type. I created a dictionary of these implementations in the constructor. Depending on how large the memory footprint of the implementations is, you may want to think about another approach - define the key value pairs in a static file (XML, config, txt, whatever) and create the correct instance using one of `System.Acticator.CreateInstance` overloads.

```
interface IFileActionHandler
{
    void PlayFile(IFile file);
}

class FileActionHandlerBase : IFileActionHandler
{
    IApp _app;

    public FileActionHandlerBase(IApp app) // It may not be needed depending on what you want to do.
    {
        _app = app;
    }

    public abstract void PlayFile(IFile file);        
}

class AudioFileActionHandler : FileActionHandlerBase
{
    public AudioFileActionHandler(IApp app)
        : base(app) { }

    public override void PlayFile(IFile file)
    {
        // Your implementation...
    }
}

class VideoFileActionHandler : FileActionHandlerBase
{
    public VideoFileActionHandler(IApp app)
        : base(app) { }

    public override void PlayFile(IFile file)
    {
        // Your implementation...
    }
}



public class PlaybackControls
    {
        private MediaPlayer player;
        private int index;

        Dictionary<string, IFileActionHandler> _fileActionHandlers;            

        public PlaybackControls(MediaPlayer player)
        {
            this.player = player;

            _fileActionHandlers = new Dictionary<string, IFileActionHandler>();
            _fileActionHandlers.Add(typeof(VideoFile).Name, new VideoFileActionHandler(player));
            _fileActionHandlers.Add(typeof(AudioFile).Name, new AudioFileActionHandler(player));
        }

        public void Seek(float pos) { }
        public void Next()
        {
            index = (index + 1) % player.Medias.Count;
            player.Current = player.Medias[index];
        }
        public void Previous()
        {
            index--;
            if (index < 0)
                index = player.Medias.Count - 1;
            player.Current = player.Medias[index];
        }

        public void Play(MediaFile media)
        {
            IsPlaying = true;

            _fileActionHandlers[media.GetType().Name].PlayFile(media);
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            Play(player.Current);
        }
        public void Pause()
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
            Seek(0);
        }
        public bool IsPlaying { get; private set; }            
    }
```

Comment: F***** AWESOME!!!! delegates @_@ - about time somebody threw an answer! Thanks a lot! I think I'm gonna go with your first approach, much easier. Do you think the 2nd approach, holds other benefits?

Comment: The second approach is useful, if you want to abstract more complicated functionality - more than one method. Now you only have Play. If you decide you want to implement FastFwd, Rewind, etc, an interface with all these methods would be more suitable.